# Finding secret changesets in Mercurial 2.8

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to get Mercurial to show me all changesets in phase secret. According to the docs, I should execute the command `hg log -r "secret()"`, but if I do that, it tells me `hg: parse error at 9: invalid token`. I'm running Mercurial 2.8

Is it possible to find the changesets I'm looking for?

Comment: What you doing should work. (I've even pasted you hg log command and seen it work) Whats odd is that you rev set string is 8 chars and yet hg parse error is at index 9. Hidden chars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be that I copied the command from somewhere, but that somewhere used quote characters that my command line didn't recognize.